# Block is repeated while creating a new layout update handler

Tags: layout, blocks, overrides, update-handle, layout-update

I recently start on Magento for one of my project and facing a few issues with a functionality i am trying to build. Basically, I want to create a separate section for customer profile. In this section, I'll bring *Account Information, Change password and Address Book*.

All worked well for Account information and Change Password but got stuck when I was trying to integrate Address Book in this new Section. Address block in main content area was repeating for `/customer/address/` page.

Here are the steps i am following.

- Created a new layout update handler in `local.xml` for customer profile

[image]

- Created a layout update handler for address book which updates `customer_profile`.

[image]

- Add Address block in `customer_address_index`.

[image]

What I am guessing here address block i am adding here is repeating because I am using same layout update handler name as in `customer.xml`, which is `customer_address_index`. Is that correct? and If it's true how can I make sure that address block is displayed only once in the page?

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem for now, I just created another layout update handler in my `custom.xml` file. Still not sure if there is any better way to do keeping the url same. For now, my url is looking some thing similar to `/customer/addressbook/index`, instead of `/customer/address/book/`.

Comment: If this solved your question please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the same block `name` value on the layout which is updating the original

```
<block name="this.should.be.same.as.parent" />
```